# Live Google search results in my website - can it be done?

Tags: api, search, search-engine, livesearch

I'm playing around with ideas for my dissertation.

Is it possible to get live search results from Google in my own webpage?

I found this example of a live search (similar to Twitters) but it uses it's own database, has Google got an API that I can access to pull through search results in a similar manner?

Example: http://demos.9lessons.info/instantsearch.php

Comment: You can find it in the [list of Google's APIs](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/): search.cse.list

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [custom search JSON api](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/over). You would need **Search engine ID** and **API key** which can be obtained from Google [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console).